# Pegar informação usando um dropdownlist como select

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Preciso fazer um sistema básico de abastecimento, onde ao selecionar o tipo de combustível, ele me traga o ultimo valor registrado daquele produto e selecione automaticamente e ainda insira automaticamente no TextBox o valor que o combustível foi comprado.

A tabela de abastecimento está puxando somente o Nome do Produto (`NomeProdutoId`) como chave estrangeira, para puxar o produto, não sei se terei que criar outra chave estrangeira para pegar o valor da tabela Compra.

Tabela Compra:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Compra] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DtCompra]    DATETIME       NULL,
[Quant]       INT            NULL,
[Tipo]        NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
[VlrUnit]     REAL           NULL,
[VlrTotal]    REAL           NULL,
[NomeId]      INT            NULL,
[NomeProduto] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK2BFDD8DA794B2666] FOREIGN KEY ([NomeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Fornecedores] ([Id])
);
```

Tabela Abastecimento:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Abastecimento] (
[Id]            INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DtAbastecido]  DATETIME   NULL,
[Litro]         INT        NULL,
[VlrUnit]       FLOAT (53) NULL,
[TotalGasto]    FLOAT (53) NULL,
[AutorId]       INT        NULL,
[NumCarroId]    INT        NULL,
[Km]            INT        NULL,
[NomeProdutoId] INT        NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK84286500787E6DCB] FOREIGN KEY ([AutorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Usuario] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK842865002F58EAD8] FOREIGN KEY ([NumCarroId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Veiculo] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK8428650023D2F9D9] FOREIGN KEY ([NomeProdutoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Compra] ([Id])
);
```

Abastecimento Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adiciona(AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
{
    /* Ver qual produto está sendo selecionado.*/
    var Produto = ckm.ConsultaProduto(viewModel.NomeProdutoId);

    viewModel.TotalGasto = viewModel.Litro * viewModel.VlrUnit;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Abastecimento abastecimento = viewModel.CriaAbastecimento();
        dao.Adiciona(abastecimento);
        //return View();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    { 
        ViewBag.Compra = compraDAO.Lista();
        ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
        ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
        return View("Form",viewModel);
    }
}
```

Classe de uso de Queries:

```
public class ControleKm : Controller
{
    private Rota r;
    private Compra c;
    private ISession session;
    public ControleKm(ISession session, Rota r, Compra c)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.r = r;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public IList<Rota> Consulta(int NumCarroId)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT r FROM Rota r";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
    }
    public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaProduto(int NomeProdutoId)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }
    public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaValor(double VlrUnit)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }

}
```

}

View de Abastecimento:

```
    @model BlogWeb.ViewsModels.AbastecimentoModel

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DtAbastecido)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.DtAbastecido , "Data Abastecido:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DtAbastecido, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { Type = "date" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Km)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Km, "Quilometragem:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Km)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Litro)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Litro, "Litros:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Litro)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.VlrUnit)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.VlrUnit, "Valor Unit:")
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.VlrUnit)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId, "Escolher Produto:")
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Compra, "Id", "NomeProduto"))

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AutorId)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.AutorId, "Responsavel Abastecimento:")
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AutorId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Usuarios, "Id", "Nome"))

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NumCarroId)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.NumCarroId, "Nº do Carro:")
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.NumCarroId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Veiculo, "Id", "NCarro"))
```

Comment: Cade as queries que você está usando?

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan está ai a classe que faz queries

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar todos os valores que você precisa é necessário fazer um `JOIN` com a Tabela compra. Vou te dar um exemplo, o `SELECT` abaixo vai retornar todas as colunas de Abastecimento e Compra mas você pode selecionar as que precisa, eu preferi usar um  `LEFT JOIN`porque ele permite retornar não só os dados relacionados das duas tabelas mas também os dados não relacionados encontrados na tabela à esquerda da clausula `JOIN`. Se não existir dados relacionados entre as tabelas nem à esquerda e nem à direita do `JOIN`, os resultados de todas as colunas da seleção da tabela à direita serão `NULL`. Mas você pode usar o `INNER JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN` se achar melhor.

```
SELECT a.*, c*
FROM Abastecimento AS a 
LEFT JOIN Compra AS c ON a.NomeProdutoId = c.Id
```

Em todas as suas outras consultas, se você quiser pegar os dados da tabela em que está fazendo o `FROM`e da tabela ligada a sua `FOREIGN KEY`, você precisa fazer um `JOIN`

Comment: Ele me mostra todas as informações que eu queria, porem não sei como faria para registra no textbox.

Comment: Coloca a `view` pra eu olhar.

Comment: Foi inserido a 'view' que é utilizada para o formulario